# How to get the current time of a youtube iframe but not in decimal?

Tags: javascript, time, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm using the YouTube iframe API to get the current time of a video. The problem is getCurrentTime() gives a decimal number and not the time as you would see it on the iframe player.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'PkZNo7MFNFg',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        console.log(player.getCurrentTime());
      }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to get the time as is displayed on the video player?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this script to convert decimal time to normal:

```
function minTommss(minutes){
 var sign = minutes < 0 ? "-" : "";
 var min = Math.floor(Math.abs(minutes));
 var sec = Math.floor((Math.abs(minutes) * 60) % 60);
 return sign + (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min + ":" + (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;
}
```

Or using moment.js:

```
function formatMinutes(mins){
  return moment().startOf('day').add(mins, 'minutes').format('m:ss');
}
```

According to the [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1) `getCurrentTime()`

> Returns the elapsed time in seconds since the video started playing.

Comment: The first one does not seem to work correctly. It doesn't return the correct time. I haven't tried moment js yet.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I tried using moment js but then again I get the wrong times. I would like the h:m:ss like in the video player.

Comment: As I've mentioned, it should return you the elapsed time in seconds. So either you convert these seconds to hours, minutes, seconds using simple math, or this is not the method you want to use. Read more here https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1

Comment: Ok then I'll do the math.

Comment: You could also try using `player.getDuration():Number` It would return the duration in seconds of the currently playing video. Note that getDuration() will return 0 until the video's metadata is loaded, which normally happens just after the video starts playing. If it is helpful, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here for anyone else who might one day need to do this. Remember that time is in seconds.

```
function convertTime(time){
        let hours = time/3600;
        let minutes = (hours - Math.floor(hours)) * 60;
        let seconds = time % 60;

        hours = Math.floor(hours);
        minutes = Math.floor(minutes);
        seconds = Math.floor(seconds);

        if ((minutes + "").length == 1){
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }

        if ((seconds + "").length == 1){
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }

        return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```